# How to use @page in printing in a certain textbox

Tags: javascript, css, printing, textarea, text-editor

I had just start learning developing a while ago and I want to create a page with 2 `text boxes` each one with `printing button` and i want :
first one to print page in `landscape`
and
second text box in `portrait`.
So i want to apply:
`@page {size: landscape;}` on first one
and
`@page {size: portrait;}`
and those text boxes are contenteditable with `id="textbox1"` and second with `id="textbox2"`
but when i tried to apply `@page` and failed with someting like this `#textbox1{@page {size: landscape;}}`
but it did not work, so please help me

> how to write and apply `@page` on certain `textbox`